# Include php file in Dreamweaver template

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I want include php file in a Dreamweaver template as below:

```
 <?php include("../attached/ad728x90-below-desktop-logo.html"); ?>
```

but receive error that "special character must escaped '<' and '>'
Please guide that how can solve it?

Comment: Please include the exact error message where possible. Is this a PHP error, or a Dreamweaver error you're getting?

Comment: It is  Dreamweaver error.

Comment: error is: "special character must escaped '<' and '>' " i have written in question.